# Calculating Average After Parsing Integers

Tags: java, average

This is for Java. 
I just finished parsing each column from String to int. However, now I am having a tough time figuring out how to calculate each column and finding the average.

For example, this is what I have after I parsed each column:

```
int Q1 = Integer.parseInt(columns[1]);
```

This is what I tried to find the average, but was unsuccessful.

```
int Q1s = Q1;


        int i;
        int total = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            total = total + Q1s;
        }

        double avg = total / Q1s;
        return avg;
```

I know how to find the average the normal way (Example: int Q1[] = {1,2,3};)
But it is not the same for parsing an array of integers.

Any hints on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I don't want the answer...I just want a direction on where to go from here. That is why I didn't put the complete code that I currently have.

Comment: why >> double avg = total / Q1s;  and not>>  double avg = total / <ColumnCount>; ?

Comment: Well, `Q1s` never changes during your loop, so you're just multiplying it by 6.  If you left out some other code inside the loop, then we can't help you.  But it looks like the problem is: what happened to the other 5 values you read?  Did you do anything with them?

Comment: do you start with two dimension array? you HAVE to put more code for us to see what you are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic to calculate `total` is wrong. You are not adding all the elements, what you're doing is adding the first element `n` times.

Assuming `Q1` is your array of `Strings`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Q1.length; ++i)
{
 total += Integer.parseInt(Q1[i]);//this is what you want to do. Parse it here
}
double avg = (double) total / Q1.length;
```

Comment: I knew something was off, but couldn't pinpoint it. I'll try that now. Thanks!

Comment: It would still give the wrong answer without typecast. Int divided by int will give int.

Answer (score 0):

```
double avg = total / Q1s;
```

Calculating average **is wrong** here. It should be

```
double avg = total / 6;
```

> It should be divided by the total number of elements here you are
>   using 6 as a constant.

Comment: This is wrong because you're doing integer division.

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1) you should use:

```
  double avg = total / <ColumnCount>;
```

2) you need to casting, So

```
  double avg = ((double)total) / <ColumnCount>;
```